# relation between sums of permutation invariant sequences (or contraction norms of symmetric tensor products)

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Over the last years, I've been trying every now and then to get any insight into the following problem without any success. It seems to be elementary so in the hope that I'm missing something obvious, I'm posting it here.

## my question

Let $(a(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4))_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers which is symmetric in the indices, i.e. $a(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)=a(i_{\sigma(1)},i_{\sigma(2)},i_{\sigma(3)},i_{\sigma(4)})$ for all permutations $\sigma \in S_4$ and square summable, i.e. $\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}^{} a_{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4}^2 < \infty$, where in this and all following sums every summation index ranges over the positive integers.

My conjecture (backed by simulations) is that
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i,j,k_1,k_2,k_3,l_1,l_2,l_3}^{} a(i,k_1,k_2,k_3) a(i,l_1,l_2,l_3) a(j,k_1,k_2,k_3) a(j,l_1,l_2,l_3)
  \geq
  \sum_{i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2,k_1,k_2,l_1,l_2}^{} a(i_1,i_2,k_1,k_2) a(i_1,i_2,l_1,l_2) a(j_1,j_2,k_1,k_2) a(j_1,j_2,l_1,l_2).
\end{equation*}

and straightforward generalizations should hold when considering sequences with more than four indices.

## observations and what I tried so far

The example where $a(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)=a(i_1)a(i_2)a(i_3)a(i_4)$ shows that equality can hold. Another instructive example, which in my opinion is some sort of extreme case, is obtained by taking $a$ to be the maximum or minimum of its indices.

Note that when considering the sequence as coefficients in an orthonormal expansion of a $4$-fold symmetric tensor product of some real separable Hilbert space, the above sums can be interpreted as the square of the norm of a tensor contraction (this is how I encountered this problem). For example, the left sum would be the inner product of a one contraction with itself. This in particular shows that both sums are non-negative. My most recent approach at a proof was purely combinatorial, hoping to apply some sort of exclusion-inclusion argument coupled with Cauchy-Schwarz. Some things to note are:

There are only three types of summands (in parentheses expicit examples for the sum on the left hand side):

1. all four coefficients are equal ($a(1,2,3,4)^{4}$),
2. there are two pairs of equal coefficients ($a(1,2,3,4)a(1,2,3,4)a(5,2,3,4)a(5,2,3,4)$),
3. all four coefficients are different ($a(1,2,3,4)a(1,5,6,7)a(8,2,3,4)a(9,5,6,7)$).

Denote the disjoint sets of summands of type 1, 2, 3 of the left sum by $S_1,S_2,S_3$ and those of the right sum by $T_1,T_2,T_3$, so that the above inequality becomes
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{\lambda \in S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3} \lambda \leq  \sum_{\lambda \in T_1 \cup T_2 \cup T_3} \lambda.
\end{equation*}

It is straightforward to see that $S_1=T_1$, $S_2\subseteq T_2$ (where the inclusion can be proper) and that in general $S_3 \cap T_3 \neq \emptyset$ but none of the sets is included in the other one. Now the symmetry (which has not been used so far) has to come into play somehow, but I don't see how.

Maybe a better way to look at this problem is to exploit the symmetry from the start by  first partitioning the sequence into equivalence classes under permutation, passing to sums of the form
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{u,v,x,y}^{} c_{u,v,x,y} a_{u}a_{v}a_{x}a_{y},
\end{equation*}
where $u$ (and analogously $v,x,y$) is of the form $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)$ with $u_1 \leq u_2 \leq u_3 \leq u_4$ and the $c_{u,v,x,y}$ are integer-valued combinatorial constants which count the number of possible pairings of $u,v,x,y$ as required by the original sums. I tried this as well but then again got stuck.

In any case, I would be very thankful for ideas how to proceed or references where related problems appear.